# How to append value in array with keys without getting overriding

Tags: php, arrays

i'm getting result in a foreach loop now i want to form a new array with keys and form that array with my new data. Now when i try to assign data it gets override to the previous one as it's not getting new index. how can i achive that so far i have done that:

```
foreach ($result as $key) {
    $pickup_location = $key->locationid;
    if (isset($pickup_location)) {
        $pickup_location = $this->db->get_where('locations', array('id' => $pickup_location ))->row();
        if (!empty($pickup_location)) {
            $supplier_dashboard['pickup_location_name'] = $pickup_location->name_en;
        }
    } 

    $dropoff_location = $key->location_dropoff;
    if (isset($dropoff_location)) {
        $dropoff_location = $this->db->get_where('locations', array('id' => $dropoff_location ))->row();
        if (!empty($dropoff_location)) { 
            $supplier_dashboard['dropoff_location_name'] = $dropoff_location->name_en;
        }
    }
    $car_make = $key->car_id;

    if (isset($car_make)) {
        $car_details = $this->db->get_where('chauffeur_rates', array('chauffeur_id' => $car_make))->row();
        if (!empty($car_details)) {
            $supplier_dashboard['car_make'] = $car_details->chauffeur_make;
        }
    }
}
return $supplier_dashboard;
}
```

and my resulting array is:

```
Array
(
 [pickup_location_name] => Seoul Downtown
 [dropoff_location_name] => Disneyland Paris
 [car_make] => makecar
)
```

however i have atleast 7 location names and car makes instead of getting added as a new array it overrides the previous one, i should have get the result as

```
Array
[0](
 [pickup_location_name] => Seoul Downtown
 [dropoff_location_name] => Disneyland Paris
 [car_make] => makecar
)
Array
[1](
 [pickup_location_name] => Seoul 1
 [dropoff_location_name] => Disneyland 1
 [car_make] => makecar
)
Array
[2](
 [pickup_location_name] => Seoul 2
 [dropoff_location_name] => Disneyland 2
 [car_make] => makecar
)
... upto 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add $key to array in which your record get added

use

```
$supplier_dashboard[$key]['pickup_location_name'] = //your code
```

instead of

```
$supplier_dashboard['pickup_location_name'] = //your code
```

Comment: already did that, its `Severity: Warning Message: Illegal offset type`

Comment: your foreach statement need to change to foreach ($result as $key => $value){}

Comment: In your code use foreach ($result as $key1 => $key ){} and in your array use $supplier_dashboard[$key1]['pickup_location_name'] = //your code

Answer (score 2):

Every time you looping the key of the array is always the same that's why you are getting overide the results. You need to put a key that is unique. You can try this

```
$i = 0; //First key
foreach ($result as $key){
    $supplier_dashboard[$i]['pickup_location_name'] = $pickup_location->name_en;
    $i++; //add +1 to the key so the next element not overrides
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the items the your array, you are directly setting the value in the top most collection.

Instad of

```
$myobject['foo'] = $value;
```

You need to do (*where `$iteration` is the current position in your loop*)

```
$myobject[$iteration]['foo'] = $value;
```

Try the following :

```
$carItemNumber = 0;
foreach ($result as $key) {
    $pickup_location = $key->locationid;
    if (isset($pickup_location)) {
        $pickup_location = $this->db->get_where('locations', array('id' => $pickup_location ))->row();

        if (!empty($pickup_location)) {
         $supplier_dashboard[$carItemNumber]['pickup_location_name'] = $pickup_location->name_en;
        }
    } 

    $dropoff_location = $key->location_dropoff;
    if (isset($dropoff_location)) {
        $dropoff_location = $this->db->get_where('locations', array('id' => $dropoff_location ))->row();

        if (!empty($dropoff_location)) { 
         $supplier_dashboard[$carItemNumber]['dropoff_location_name'] = $dropoff_location->name_en;
        }
    }

    $car_make = $key->car_id;

    if (isset($car_make)) {
        $car_details = $this->db->get_where('chauffeur_rates', array('chauffeur_id' => $car_make))->row();

        if (!empty($car_details)) {
         $supplier_dashboard[$carItemNumber]['car_make'] = $car_details->chauffeur_make;
        }
    }

    $carItemNumber++;
}
return $supplier_dashboard;
```